# What would be wrong with this function that return a rounded number in millions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner doing an online course using ipython notebook and panda.

We are given a function

```
def roundToMillions (value):
    result = round(value / 1000000)
    return result
```

and some tests

```
roundToMillions(4567890.1) == 5

roundToMillions(0) == 0  # always test with zero...

roundToMillions(-1) == 0 # ...and negative numbers

roundToMillions(1499999) == 1 # test rounding to the nearest
```

We are told .. ***Define a few more test cases for both functions*** .

I can't think of any more tests though.

The question posed is:

***Why can't you use roundToMillions() to round the population to millions of inhabitants?***

I don't quite understand what could be wrong with the function.

This course is free and so there is not really much help available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of test cases, this loop will generate many test cases and the results speak for themselves:

```
for x in xrange(-2000000, 2000000, 250000):
print roundToMillions(x), x
>> -2.0 -2000000 
>> -2.0 -1750000
>> -2.0 -1500000
>> -2.0 -1250000
>> -1.0 -1000000
>> -1.0 -750000
>> -1.0 -500000
>> -1.0 -250000
>> 0.0 0
>> 0.0 250000
>> 0.0 500000
>> 0.0 750000
>> 1.0 1000000
>> 1.0 1250000
>> 1.0 1500000
>> 1.0 1750000
```

So obviously it's rounding down.

This is due to integer division. removing the round shows this:

```
def roundToMillions (value):
    result = value / 1000000
    return result
print roundToMillions(999999)
>> 0
```

This is fixed by adding a .0 to the function:

```
def roundToMillions (value):
    result = round(value / 1000000.0)
    return result

for x in xrange(0, 1000000, 250000):
    print roundToMillions(x), x
>> 0.0 0
>> 0.0 250000
>> 1.0 500000
>> 1.0 750000
print roundToMillions(999999)
>> 1.0
```

For more on integer division have a look at

```
print (3/2)
>> 1
print (3.0/2.0)
>> 1.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  In your code 1750000 rounds down to 1 right?

Comment: when i run roundToMillions(1750000) the answer value returned is 2

Comment: Try it with 500,000 and 1,500,000. If these round correctly, then your function is correct.

Comment: I'm confused 1,500000 rounds to 2 which seems ok.

Comment: the function is supposedly wrong.  I didnt write it though it is included as an expample and something is meant to be wrong with it.]

Comment: It doesn't work on my complier so it is wrong. Nevertheless, the answer is that you cant use integer division. You need to replace 1000000 with 1000000.0 in the function.